# How to initialize a queue with n default values?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, queue

Say I have a class with default constructor. How can I initialize a queue in constructor by settings its size and a default value.

```
class StandardClass
{};

// will initialize a vector with 5 default standard class 
std::vector<StandardClass> vec(5, StandardClass());
```

How do I do the same with queue?

```
std::queue<StandardClass> que(5, StandardClass()); ???
```

Comment: To my knowledge there is no equivalent constructor.

Comment: That code isn't valid C++ :-(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at e.g. [this `std::queue` constructor reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/queue) you will see that you can pass an instance of the underlying container (defaults to [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque)).

So you should be able do something like

```
std::queue<StandardClass> que(std::deque<StandardClass>(5));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it the following way

```
std::queue<StandardClass> que
    ( std::queue<StandardClass>::container_type( 5, StandardClass()  ) );
```

Or more simpler

```
std::queue<StandardClass> que
    ( std::queue<StandardClass>::container_type( 5 ) );
```

Comment: @user2822838 Take into account that the example I showed is most correct because it does not depend on underlaying container.